# Swagger for spring boot describing parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger

My question is pretty simple:
having rest controller's params like

```
(  @RequestBody Wrapper<Request> requestBody){...}
```

i got to customize UI view of model `Wrapper<Request>`. It has some fields and I use it from different starter. Im able to put @Schema(required=true) on the field of Request, cause it's located in my module, but what about Wrapper ? Thx.

Comment: A little bit of clarification to my original post. Im capable of copying all generated swagger code to swagger editor. Than i simply put required: true onto model property and it renders as I wish it would in my dev environment. So, how to override property with annotation or Docket bean customization ? Just a final field from different jar. I bet there is solution.

Comment: I also saw  swagger-config.yaml overriding examples, but didn't get it at all.

Comment: So, find out solution through spring fox docs. If I alternate TypeRules writing custom DocketBean it substitutes model definition in swagger.

Answer (score 1):

> This is related to #1490.The way to configure this is to create a
> custom alternateTypeRules in the Docket config. For e.g. if you have
> an immutable MyClass that generates ImmutableMyClass, then we would
> add a rule for it as shown below.

```
@Bean
public Docket docket() {
  return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .alternateTypeRules(AlternateTypeRules.newRule(MyClass.class,
                ImmutableMyClass.class));
```

https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#answers-to-common-questions-and-problems , see #22. It has side effects like resetting all custom settings.